# Create DTS config file with Excel fo SSIS package

Tags: xml, excel, ssis

I have create a SSIS package that only requires 5 of the variables to change when it is run, I have provided example below

1. [User::FolderStem] : 0914
2. Loop 1-22 IF.Properties[EvalExpression] @RunNo<23
3. Loop 1-22 IF.Properties[InitExpression] @RunNo=1
4. Loop 1-14 NB.Properties[EvalExpression] @RunNo<15
5. Loop 1-14 NB.Properties[InitExpression] @RunNo=1

I have been trying to get excel to export a usable .dtsConfig file so that I can keep user invovlement to a minimum.

My dream is that I can have the user select a few options in Excel and then fire and forget.

I have built an XML schema and seem able to produce an xml file that on the face of it seems to match exactly that produced when I use the config wizard in SSIS

However, whenever I execute the package, wither within SSIS or standalone, i get

```
Warning: Failure importing configuration file: "C:\ICA.dtsConfig".
```

When I open the config in IE, it displays fine, so I havent crumbed up the xml.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to marry the Moon to the sun. Not going to happen.

Comment: is there anyway at all to auotmate the changeing of the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going wrong with your process, but I have a few tings to check and an alternative that might serve you as "close enough"

First the testing:
Check permissions and ownership on the created file. If your working config and your failing "modified" config don't have the same ownership and permissions, try changing the modified one to match the working one.

Create your "modified" config file to use the same values as your working one. Does this one work? Compare the files, is there any difference you can see? Maybe capitalization differences, or XML document properties?

If the files look the same, look at them in a hex editor, are there any white space characters that are different? Maybe line termination characters?

Now the alternative:
Almost all of the SSIS properties have the option to set the property from a variable instead of a specific value. You can read in the variables from a flat file or a table, and then set the property from the variable. For example, the FTP task has a "IsLocalPathVariable" and if that's set to true, it reads the path out of whatever you set as the variable. Sometimes the way to set it is with an "edit function" button on the property (like a query in a dataset, for example) and you can use the variable in the function that sets the property. You often have to set "reasonable" default values and/or delay validation on the properties you are setting this way.

It's definitely more work than using the config system, but it does work. I drive most of my packages from a version of this approach (though it's much more complicated. So complicated, in fact, that I have a template that handles loading the config values so I don't have to re-code it with each package).

EDIT:
One more thought! One configuration option is to read them from a database, and Excel can update values in a database. I have no idea if the security implications would put this out of the question (it might be hared to secure, or if the inherent security prevents Excel from writing to that particular database), but if the testing doesn't point to a solution and the above alternative looks like too much work, letting Excel update the configuration database (possibly through a stored procedure) might be a better fit.